# how I can display multiple videos on different QT widgets at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, video, opencv

I have done a code which run different algorithms of OpenCV on different QWidgets .. so I have 3 tabs and each should show a camera live streaming with the processing of them .. I take the capture of the video at the first tab widget and pass it by global reference to the other tabs... however I get this problem

```
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
```

although I have only one capture ..

any ideas?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Qt

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this issue is **copy the frame retrieved by the camera** and make it available to the other tabs. **Do not** share the `capture` interface!

Comment: I am already implementing that in my code, that's why I am confused about the error..

Comment: That message is clearly stating that the problem is related to your camera device. Maybe the capture code is being executed twice? Are you setting any particular property of the camera before or while the frames are being captured?

Comment: are you absolutely sure? If you add a print statement before the `while` loop responsible for retrieving the frames from the camera, can you verify that it is only being executed once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with OpenCV and Qt. For emulating a camera I'm using the Capture object to read frames from a video file and send them over TCP/IP.

To make your frames available to all the others widgets I suggest to you to create a new class that inherits from QIODevice, initialize your capture device. Every time you get a new frame from the camera, you save the data into a QByteArray variable and emits the readyRead() signal.

Note:
 - all your widgets have to be connected to the readyRead() signal
 - once you get a new frame, remember to clean previous data
 - you have to re-implement function `virtual qint64 readData( char * data, qint64 maxSize )` to be able to read your data

Something like this

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

class VideoCaptureDevice : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VideoCaptureDevice(QObject *parent);
    virtual ~VideoCaptureDevice();

private:
    VideoCapture            m_capture;
    QByteArray      m_receivedData;

protected:
    // from QIODevice
    qint64 writeData(const char * data, qint64 maxSize);
    qint64 readData(char * data, qint64 maxSize);

};
```